# How to set different font-weights for headlines in bootstrap v4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Within my website design, various headlines (`h1, h2, h3`) have various font-weights. E.g. `h2` is bold while `h1` is regular.

Within my `custom.scss`, I can only override bootstraps `$headings-font-weight`. Unfortunately, this sets the weight for all headings.

What is the best way to override the font-weight for just `h2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the style of `h2` in your `custom.scss`.

```css
h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already, but it did not work. Based on your answer I tried again and I have to point out the order of the style. This style must be placed after `@import` statement.